# Why the query runs again when i reload the page and can not click on the post button to insert any data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a medical related site in php. When a patient logged in and he did not post any thing but he refreshes the page the query retrieve the old records again which is already inserted kindly help
 This is my code for 
 Patient_dashboard.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$ufn = "";
$uln = "";
$q2 = "";
$post="";
$query;
$query2="";



$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
 if(! $connection )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$database = mysqli_select_db($connection,"medical_network");
if (!$database) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

require_once("Functions/functions.php");

$posts = get_user_posts($_SESSION['id']);
$uploadDir = 'Reports Images/'; //Image Upload Folder

if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& !empty($_POST['submit'])){

        $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];   
        $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
        $filename = $fileName;
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $date = date_create();
        $fileName= date_timestamp_get($date).".".$ext;
        $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
            $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
        }


        $post = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,($_POST['np_text']));
        //$date = date("Y/m/d");
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //echo $date;
        $query = "INSERT INTO post ";
        $query .= "(p_pic,p_content,p_date,u_id) VALUES (";
        $query .= "'{$filePath}','{$post}','{$date}','{$_SESSION['id']}');";

        //echo $query . "  " .$date;

        $result_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if (!$result_set) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }


    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Medical Network</title>
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt);
}        
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topmenu">
        <div class="search">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Profile</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='logout.php'><span>Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left-colum">
        <div class="profileinfo">
            <div class="profilepic">
            <?php echo "<img class='getPic' src='{$_SESSION['pic']}' />" ?>
            </div>
            <div class="personal-info">
                <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'><span><?php echo  $_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname']; ?></span></a></li>
                       <li><a href='#'><span>Edit Profile</span></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="importantlinks">
            <h4>Important Links</h4>
                <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'><span>Make Appointment</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href='#'><span>Search Doctor</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href='logout.php'><span>Logout</span></a></li>
                </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="pages">
            <h4>Pages</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-colum">
    <div id="feeds">
                <div class="new-post">
                    <ul>

                         <form method="post" action="patient-dashboard.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                             <li><a href="#"><label for="newpostfield"><img src="images/status.png" width="14" height="14"> Update Status</label></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> <img src="images/photo.png" width="14" height="14"> Add Photo                              </a>
                        </li>
                        <input type="file" id="myFile"    name="image" size="4
                000000" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png"   />


                    </ul>
                    <br />

                        <textarea rows="1" cols="40" id="newpostfield" name="np_text" placeholder="Whats on your mind ?" required="required" ></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" id="postbtn"/>
                    </form>

                </div><!--End of feed-item -->


                <br />
                <div class="posts-feed">
                    <h3 id="postsheading" class="post-heading">Posts</h3>

                        <?php while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)){ 
                            $counter = 0;
                        ?>

                        <div class="post">

                        <div class="poster-pic">
                            <?php echo "<img src='{$_SESSION['pic']}' height='60' width='60' />" ?>
                        </div><!--End of poster-pic -->
                        <div class="post-content">

                            <div id="poster-name"><a href="profile.php"><?php echo  $_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname']; ?></a><span></span></div>
                            <div id="content">
                                <p id="post-text">
                                <?php
                                     echo $post['p_content']."<br/>";
                                     $img = $post['p_pic'];
                                     echo "<a href='#'> <img src='{$post['p_pic']}' height='300' width='300' >"

                                     ?>
                                 </p>
                            </div><br />
                            <div id="post-responses" class="top-border">

                               <a href="#">Comment</a> 


                            </div>

                        </div><!--End of post-content -->

                    </div><!--End of post -->

                                    <?php $counter++; 
                                    } ?>

            </div><!--End of feeds -->


    </div>
    <div class="right-colum">
        <div class="heading">
            <h4>Recommended Pages</h4>
        </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is function.php where i am retrieving the records.

```
<?php 

function get_user_posts($id) {
        global $connection;
    $query2 = "SELECT p_pic, p_content,u_id ";
        $query2 .= "FROM post ";
        $query2 .= "WHERE u_id= " . $id ." ";
        $query2 .= "ORDER BY p_id DESC ";
        $query2 .= "LIMIT 5";
        $result_set1 = mysqli_query( $connection,$query2);
        if (!$result_set1) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }


        // REMEMBER:
        // if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false
        if ($result_set1) {
            return $result_set1;
        } else {
            return NULL;
            die("query faild..... in get post");
        } 
}
?>
```

Comment: If you mean that after you've submitted the form, reloading the page results in a resubmit, that's the normal behavior. (You are getting a prompt that asks your confirmation on the form resubmission process).

Comment: I have some records in my database when i refresh it insert the old records and also fetch them means duplication

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `$posts = get_user_posts($_SESSION['id']);` outside the if statement so it is showing the records as on every reload it is fetching the data. if you want to display the records only if it is posted then put it inside the if statement

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    //your code

    $posts = get_user_posts($_SESSION['id']);
}
```

and please do check the if the variables are available or not.

Comment: Anyone help me i am waiting for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please change input name attribute

it should be:

use any name Except submit

also change
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& !empty($_POST['submit'])){

Comment: i changed it but the problem is different